# Making a graph inside a leaflet popup using geoJson data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, geojson

I'm working on a map that uses leaflet and is populated by data from a file in a GeoJson format. My overarching goal is to put graphs into the leaflet popups for each marker on the map.

Getting the markers for each feature and getting the popups to open was fairly easy. However, I am finding it difficult to use D3 to add to the popup.

For the sake of simplicity my goal at the moment is to use D3 to create a svg within each leaflet popup div and draw a square.

I have found some examples where people have used D3 to create graphs inside leaflet popups, but none of them were also using geoJson and the onEachFeature function. This is one of the examples:http://jsfiddle.net/6UJQ4/

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
L.geoJson( data,  {
    style: function (feature) {
        return { opacity: 0, fillOpacity: 0.5, fillColor: "#0f0" };
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){

        var graph_container = '<div class="popupGraph" id="graph" style="width: 200px; height:200px;"></div>';

        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name + '<br>' + graph_container);    

        var svg = d3.select("#graph").selectAll("svg").append("svg").attr("width", 50).attr("height", 200);   

        var rectangle = svg.append("rect").attr("width", 25).attr("height", 25);

    }
}).addTo(map);
```

I believe I am having issues because D3 can't find the graph_container div however I am a little stumped on how to fix this.

If anyone has any experience using D3, Leaflet, and geoJson together and could explain to me how to get my square to show in the popups or if anyone knows of a source that could help me. I would appreciate it a lot. 
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**: Bits has solved my problem! If anyone needs a working example of using D3 in Leaflet popups in combination with GeoJson, Bits posted it in the comments but I will post it here aswell: http://jsfiddle.net/2XfVc/132/

Comment: You need to attach that element to the DOM before you can use it in D3.

Comment: How would I attach an element inside of a popup to the DOM?

Comment: For example with D3's `.append()`. What you're creating in `graph_container` is really only a string and won't change anything on the page.

Comment: `svg` element could be appended to the newly inserted `div` programatically afterwards. IMO It doesn't have to be added to DOM before you can use D3.

Comment: @Lars Never mind my last comment, I get what you mean now; But `bindPopup` and `openPopup` will take care of converting the div's string into actual DOM.

Comment: You're right about that, but the D3 code (`d3.select("#graph")`) won't select anything before its part of the DOM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its quite simple, you just need to add and `svg` element inside of your div. And start coding d3.

Give me a moment, I am updating your fiddle.

**Update**: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/6UJQ4/6/

I took the liberty of simplifying/stripping your example to lowest common denominator to reduce confusion.

**Update**: http://jsfiddle.net/6UJQ4/7/

In the previous fiddle, you will come across issues where all your markers will be selected everytime giving undesired results. So use last update.

Comment: Is it possible to add this functionality to the markers from inside the onEachFeature function when using GeoJson?

Comment: Why not? If you could make a fiddle that pulls GeoJson data from somewhere and has that code which is mentioned in your question, then I can look at that.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for the help. I've tried to merge the code you gave me earlier to fit my situation but the svg isn't showing. I quickly made this and it resembles what is happening in my actual project: http://jsfiddle.net/2XfVc/129/

Comment: You were misusing leaflet as well. You had to create a [Popup object](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup) and it takes care of click handlers. Here is a working fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/2XfVc/132/](http://jsfiddle.net/2XfVc/132/)

Comment: Thank you! Sorry if I was making some basic mistakes, this is my first time using javascript.

Comment: Is there any way to do the same in RStudio Shiny? Thanks!