# Creating graph inside a specific leaflet popup using select by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, leaflet

I have a leaflet map and trying get it to work with D3.

I use a GeoJSON file to create leaflet popups for each feature.

Now I want to create a graph in a specific popup. I tried to select it by `#ID`.  But that didn't work.

As a source I used this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465089/making-a-graph-inside-a-leaflet-popup-using-geojson-data?rq=1)

To make my point more clear I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hpfcryc/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your JSFiddle example, you create the same popup content with an `<svg>` tag and apply some SVG content using d3, for all of your GeoJSON features (i.e. within `onEachFeature`).

If I understand correctly, you would like to create SVG content only for specific features' popup. So you tried to set some ID on the popup.

A straight forward solution would be to  simply create your specific SVG content only for the features of interest.

You can access the feature properties with `feature.properties` to know whether it should have a special popup content or not:

```js
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
  var div = $('<div id="' + feature.properties.name + '" style="width: 200px; height:200px;"><svg/></div>')[0];
  var popup = L.popup().setContent(div);

  layer.bindPopup(popup);

  if (feature.properties.name === 'test1') {
    var svg = d3.select(div).select("svg").attr("width", 200).attr("height", 200);
    svg.append("rect").attr("width", 150).attr("height", 150).style("fill", "lightBlue");
  }
}
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1hpfcryc/4/