# d3.js graph in leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I'm trying to add a d3.js graph to a leaflet popup. I looked into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465089/making-a-graph-inside-a-leaflet-popup-using-geojson-data) and it seems to be in the right direction but for some reason I'm getting `[object HTMLDivElement]` instead of the actual contents of the `div`. Any ideas?

Here is my code for the popup so far (right now I'm only trying to add a circle):

```
function showPopup(latlng, name, comuna, estrato1, estrato2, estrato3, estrato4, estrato5, estrato6) {
  var div = $('<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></svg></div>')[0];
  var svg = d3.select(div).select("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200);
  svg.append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("r", 100)
    .attr("cx", 100)
    .attr("cy", 100);
  popup
  .setLatLng(latlng)
  .setContent('<b>' + name.toUpperCase() + '</b><p>' + comuna.toUpperCase() + '</p><p class="estratos">Estrato 1: ' + Math.round(estrato1 * 100) + '%<br>Estrato 2: ' + Math.round(estrato2 * 100) +'%<br>Estrato 3: ' + Math.round(estrato3 * 100) +'%<br>Estrato 4: ' + Math.round(estrato4 * 100) +'%<br>Estrato 5: ' + Math.round(estrato5 * 100) +'%<br>Estrato 6: ' + Math.round(estrato6 * 100) +'%</p>' + div)
  .openOn(mymap);
}
```

Comment: Could you post an example on fiddle...

Comment: I'm not sure if this would generate the error you are seeing, but you don't have an svg in your div: `<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></svg></div>`

Comment: @AndrewReid The svg is supposed to be created through d3. But even if I remove all the svg lines, and I only leave the declaration of the `div` variable (`var div = $('<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>')[0];`) I still get the same `[object HTMLDivElement]` instead of the actual `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The key was in getting rid of the jQuery stuff when declaring the `div`, adding an `id` to the `div` and then putting the d3 part once the `div` has been inserted into the popup. Here's the revised code:

```
function showPopup(latlng, name, comuna, estrato1, estrato2, estrato3, estrato4, estrato5, estrato6) {
  var div = '<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" id="graphDiv"></svg></div>';
  popup
    .setLatLng(latlng)
    .setContent('<b>' + name.toUpperCase() + '</b><p>' + comuna.toUpperCase() + '</p><p class="estratos">Estrato 1: ' + Math.round(estrato1 * 100) + '%<br>Estrato 2: ' + Math.round(estrato2 * 100) +'%<br>Estrato 3: ' + Math.round(estrato3 * 100) +'%<br>Estrato 4: ' + Math.round(estrato4 * 100) +'%<br>Estrato 5: ' + Math.round(estrato5 * 100) +'%<br>Estrato 6: ' + Math.round(estrato6 * 100) +'%</p>' + div)
    .openOn(mymap);
  var svg = d3.select("#graphDiv").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200);
  svg.append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("r", 100)
    .attr("cx", 100)
    .attr("cy", 100);
}
```